# Adding a new LLVM codegen option for RustC

Tags: rust, llvm, rust-cargo

I started learning/working on the Rust compiler very recently. The command line to compile rust code with rustc has multiple code gen options, one of which is `llvm-args`, which allows the user to specify the configuration of the LLVM-backend. I want to add a new flag to `llvm-args`, but struggle to come up with an implementation plan.

I have looked at some PRs on the Rust repo (PRs [41847](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41847) and [27260](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/27260)) where people try to create new flags for the Rust compiler, but still couldn't map out a procedure that I should follow to complete my task. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on this topic.